# Ошибка в условии цикла

Tags: javascript

К примеру приходят такие данные
Все окей.

```
{
    "msg": "OK"
}
```

ошибка когда

```
{
    "msg": "Error: profile does not exist"
}
```

Когда приходит ОК заходит в первую ветвь, в когда приходит Error во-вторую ветвь не заходит почему то

```
    if (typeof data.msg !== 'OK') {
        console.log("Ок");

    } else {
        console.log("Не ок");
    }
```

Comment: Напишите хотя бы как как вы получаете `data.msg`. Данные как я понял приходит в JSON-формате. Вы декодируете эти данные в объект?

Comment: я делаю если ошибка `$err = array("Error1" => "Error: usersid not set");` и вывожу `echo json_encode($err);`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
if (typeof data.msg == "string" && data.msg === 'OK') {
    console.log("Ок");

} else {
    console.log("Не ок");
}
```

Вы неправильно используете typeof . Оператор typeof возвращает тип аргумента.
Результатом typeof является строка, содержащая тип:

```
typeof undefined // "undefined"
typeof 0 // "number"
typeof true // "boolean"
typeof "foo" // "string"
typeof {} // "object"
typeof null // "object"  (1)
typeof function(){} // "function"  (2)
```

Последние две строки помечены, потому что typeof ведет себя в них по-особому.

Взято [отсюда](https://learn.javascript.ru/types-intro)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
if(data.msg == 'OK') {
   console.log("Ок");
}
else {
   console.log("Не ок");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
if(data.msg === 'OK') {
   console.log("Ок");
}
else {
   console.log("Не ок");
}
```